# DeMorgans Law: clarification between different types

Tags: elementary-set-theory

btw. I've looked hard and watched alot of videos to try and learn this but I'm really at a loss.

I'm have proved a version of de-morgans laws, but unsure as to what type it is:
the two questions i have are: 
[image]

The only way I know how to prove de-morgans laws are as follows:

1.9a
start with the complement of the union of all A $$\left (\cup _{\alpha }A_{\alpha }  \right )^{c}$$ $\omega$ is all of the sample space that isn't in an 'A' set:
[image]

So for all sets, $\omega$ is in the complement, so $\omega$ is not in $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ and $A_{3}$ and $A_{n}$
Therefore $\omega$ must be in $A_{1}^{C}$ and $A_{2}^{C}$ and $A_{3}^{C}$ and $A_{n}^{C}$
therefore $\omega$ must be in the intersection of each complement of 'A' sets. i.e.
$$\cap _{\alpha }A^{c}_{\alpha }$$
therefore: $$\left (\cup _{\alpha }A_{\alpha }  \right )^{c}=\cap _{\alpha }A^{c}_{\alpha }$$

So my problem now is to me this proof works for finite/countable and infinite/uncountable collection of sets,
Did I just do 1.9a or 1.10?